# How to flushright text and flushleft text and have them horizontally aligned?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, signatures

I want to create something similar to this:
[image]

Where the **City, Date** is flushed left and the **First Name Last Name** is flushed right and has a signature line above it, where I want to add a image with a signature.
I have following code at the moment:

```
\begin{flushright}
    \includegraphics[width=2.5in, keepaspectratio]{images/singature.jpg}
\end{flushright}
\begin{flushright}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}p{2.25in}@{}}
    \hrulefill \\
    John Doe
    \end{tabular}
\end{flushright}
\begin{flushleft}
City, Date
\end{flushleft}
```

It doesn't align the **City, Date** and **First Name Last Name** text however.
I would like to have those two horizontally aligned.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Dankeschön, Mensch! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the standard `tabular*`, with the help of `booktabs`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\noindent X\dotfill X\par\medskip% to see the margins

\noindent
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ll@{}}
Somewhere, 26 August 2022
& \includegraphics[width=2.5in,height=0.7in]{example-image} \\
\cmidrule(r){1-1}
\cmidrule(l){2-2}
\footnotesize City, Date & \footnotesize Signature
\end{tabular*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

[image]

With use of table (written by use of the `tabularray` package) is simple:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\noindent%
\begin{tblr}{colspec ={l X @{} l},
             abovesep=11pt, belowsep=0pt
              }  
Maribor, August 26, 2022    
            &&   \includegraphics[width=55mm, height=22mm]{images/singature.jpg}\\[2ex]
    \cline{3-3}
City, Date  &&  First and Last name
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```